# What does 自重を支える mean?

Tags: translation, meaning

How do you pronounce 自重? Is it じじゅう or じちょう?  In this context, what does it mean?

The entire sentence is,

> その**自重**を支える魂の翼持つ「冒険者」よ、竜と巨人が、魔獣と亜人が住まう、幻想の世界セルデシア。

What does this phrase mean approximately?

Comment: With the soulful wing to support your weight, adventurer, now you have entered this mythical world Serdesia where dragons, giants, demons, 亜人 inhabit.

Answer (score 2):

I'd like to know the whole sentence because the の doesn't make sense.

> その自重を支える魂の翼持つ「冒険者」よ

means:

> ***Hey, the "adventurers" who have the spiritual/imaginary wings to support their weight, ...***

In this context, it's obvious that

**自重（じじゅう）= the weight of oneself = one's weight** .

自重（じちょう）する means to "to take good care of oneself" and it doesn't fit in this context.

Comment: The entire sentence is: その自重を支える魂の翼持つ「冒険者」よ、竜と巨人が、魔獣と亜人が住まう、幻想の世界セルデシア。

Comment: So 魂 was missing. Okay, I see. I'll edit it now. Thanks!

Comment: My bad! I missed a character in the original post. Thank you for your help! If you don't mind translating, how would you write that entire sentence in English?

Comment: That is the problem. The whole sentence doesn't make sense. It should be the abbreviation of その自重を支える魂の翼持つ「冒険者」よ、ここが竜と巨人が、魔獣と亜人が住まう、幻想の世界セルデシアなのだ。or  その自重を支える魂の翼持つ「冒険者」よ、竜と巨人が、魔獣と亜人が住まう、幻想の世界セルデシアへようこそ。

Comment: Hey, the "adventurers" who have the spiritual/imaginary wings to support their weight, welcome to the delusional world, Seldesia, where dragons, giants, monsters, and 亜人　live. Or,  Hey, the "adventurers" who have the spiritual/imaginary wings to support their weight, this is the delusional world, Seldesia, where dragons, giants, monsters, and 亜人　live.

Comment: I see. That's strange as I got this sentence directly from a light novel (Log Horizon). Thank you for your help!

Comment: I don't know what 亜人 means here. I can think of "Asians."   or "natives."

Comment: The abbreviation can be possible if it's a light novel. The writer may prefer an ungrammatical version in order to leave a strong impression on purpose.

Comment: 全体の文脈には[ここ](http://anime.xair.biz/aniho/%E3%83%AD%E3%82%B0%E3%83%BB%E3%83%9B%E3%83%A9%E3%82%A4%E3%82%BA%E3%83%B3)にあります。「その自重を支える魂の翼持つ冒険者」というのは「自律的に行動し、死んでも復活できる特性を持った、冒険者と呼ばれる人々」のことを指しているようですね。

Comment: narutoさん、とても役にたつ書き込みありがとうございます。According
 to the whole context, the original sentence would be:その自重を支える魂の翼持つ「冒険者」よ、竜と巨人が、魔獣と亜人が住まう、幻想の世界セルデシア...に己の生を刻み込め。

Comment: セルでシアの後の句点「○」の数個は、本来は読点「、」であって次につながっている所を、筆者が意図的に文章を小切れよくするために句点を用いてカットしたために生じた混乱であった、と解釈いたしました。